# How to make a constructor of class that inherits from another class in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am newcomer to Python language and I have question about inheritance.

Suppose this is my code:

```
class LogicGate(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.label = n
        self.output = None

    def get_label(self):
        return self.label

    def get_output(self):
        self.output = self.perform_gate_logic()
        return self.output

class BinaryGate(LogicGate):
    def __init__(self, n):
        LogicGate.__init__(self, n)

        self.pinA = None
        self.pinB = None
```

This is how I see implementation of python object system. Object is just a  bunch of variable, methods lives somewhere else. In order for methods to to do some work on particular object I pass 'self' in every method. (if this totally not true, please correct me)

But, I don't understand this:

```
LogicGate.__init__(self, n)
```

could you explain what's going here? I'm using python 2.7

Comment: What part isn't clear? Your subclass provided a new `__init__` method, so the one on `LogicGate` won't be called unless you do so explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All python methods are in fact "just functions". Even special methods, like `__init__` are actually just a normal function, that accepts two parameters - `self` (which could actualy have any name - `self` is only a convention) and `n`.

When you create an instance, python creates the instance and passes it as `self` automaticaly to `__init__` method. So, for example you can create `LogicGate` instance manually:

```
>>> x = object.__new__(LogicGate)
>>> x
<__main__.LogicGate object at 0x7f12b2ea49d0>
    # This won't work, because x instance is not initialized
>>> x.label
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'LogicGate' object has no attribute 'label'
>>> LogicGate.__init__(x, 'foo')
>>> x.label
'foo'
```

When you want to do initialization from parent class, you must call its `__init__` - which is exaclty what `LogicGate.__init__(self, n)` actually does. It just calls `__init__` method of `LogicGate` class with your instance as the first parameter.

Edit: you should probably use method resolution order, instead of directly calling parent's `__init__`, i.e.:

```
super(BinaryGate, self).__init__(n)
```

This just make sure it will call prober parent class, so if you change it to, something like `SuperLogicGate`, you won't have to change the call to parent's `__init__` too.

You should probably also read this: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=class%20inheritance

Comment: So, the main point of doing this is to have initialization from parent class. Is this correct ? I mean to call parent constructor in child class

Comment: @NikitaLuparev - exactly. You have to realize that in python, there is very little "class/object magic" - it's quite simple - when you want initialization from parent class, you just call it (and it doesn't really matters if directly or by using `super()`). In fact, you can call *ANY* class's `__init__`, or it can be just some regular function which adds something to `self`.